# c# Two FileStreams write to text file but just one affect file

Tags: c#, filestream

below code:

```
  var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\tools\test.txt", 
   FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

  var fs2 = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\tools\test.txt", 
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        int a = 0;
        while (a < 3)
        {
            byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("DEF_");
            byte[] info2 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("abc_");
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            fs2.Write(info2, 0, info2.Length);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            ++a;
        }

        fs.Close();
        fs2.Close();
```

Why result is that in a file there is just "abc_abc_abc" ?
FileShare.ReadWrite means for me other processes/threads can write to this file in the same time in FileStream ctor call.

Comment: `fs2` closed after `fs`, so it overwrote the contents written by `fs1`.  Two streams cannot simultaneously write to the same file.  Whichever one saves last will win.

Comment: So tell me what Is a sense of flag FileShare.None then if I have the same result when I put FileShare.WReadWrite ? 
How can cheat it?
Generally I want to reproduce a problem where two FileStreams writes simultaneously to the same file and achieve it (does not need to be FileStream)

Comment: To achieve that you need to open and close the filestreams for every write

Comment: anyway for the race condition if there are some threads writing simultaneously to the same file you still can loose data

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a single stream?  Two streams might share the same file, but they do not share their positions in that file, and whichever stream saves last will win.  These problems don't exist when using a single stream.  `FileShare.ReadWrite` means a process can open a file for reading while another process has a write lock on that file.  It isn't meant for multiple processes writing to the same file simultaneously.  You're much better off sharing a single file stream.

Comment: Guys what I want to achieve is to write simple console application and as result to have two different data written by it's two processes which run in the same time ( reproduce problematic situation)

Comment: None of that is in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior as follows:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var fs2 = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("DEF_");
    byte[] info2 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("abc_");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        fs.Flush();

        fs2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs2.Write(info2, 0, info2.Length);
        fs2.Flush();
    }
}
```

Before writing, each pointer of stream must be positioned at the end. This is done using the `Seek` method.

After writing, you need to flush the buffer to disk. This ensures that the stream is in the correct state before starting the next write. To do this, use the `Flush` method.

---

When you create a stream in its constructor, you can specify the `FileOptions.WriteThrough`. According to its description, the intermediate buffer should not be used. However, it still doesn't work without the `Flush` method. Perhaps experts will explain the reason.